# How to pass user principle to rest endpoint using postman

Tags: rest, postman

Hi We have a rest end point and if it is expecting user principle in its request object how to send the same from your postman tool explicitly

Answer (score 1):

I hope what you implies by 'user principle' is the user authentication. Then you are referring on how we can send REST commands with including authentication information (token, etc.) 
Currently postman supports Basic Auth, Digest Auth, OAuth 1.0a, OAuth 2, Hawk and AWS authentication.
If what you are handling in the server is one of them, then please refer [this link](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/authorization) to see how we can prepare the authentication details in the Postman request.

If its a custom method, then please examine the 'Header', 'Cookies' and other relevant titles in [this page](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/requests) and prepare the postman request according to what you are expecting from the server-side manually.

Comment: so is it something to do with token i.e authorization? we are using getUserPrinciple method where it is returning null..and i am passing JWT key also...is it possible that the JWT is invalid? and causing this issue

Comment: I think it might be better if you first identify where the problem occurs. Postman is just sending whatever we configured in there. So by looking at logs from server-side or debugging you may first get confirmed if the request comes to the server and if it is properly handled upto the place where you do JWT validation. If it is coming properly, then its an error with your JWT mechanism. If the request is not hitting the server-side anyhow, then its a problem in the network.

Comment: I have decoded the JWt and found it is not having the user principle in PayLoad